# Gson; list of objects in list of objects

Tags: java, android, gson

I have json which looks like this:

```
[{
    "id":14,
    "namelanguage1":"Książka",
    "namelanguage2":"das Buch",
    "tags":
    [{
        "id":2,
        "name":"Szkoła",
        "language_user_id":null,
        "created_at":"2014-04-11T17:30:28.356Z",
        "updated_at":"2014-04-11T17:30:28.356Z",
        "user_id":2
    }],
    "language1_id":5,
    "language2_id":1,
},
{
    "id":15,
    "namelanguage1":"das Fußball",
    "namelanguage2":"Piłka nożna",
    "tags":[{
        "id":2,
        "name":"Szkoła",
        "language_user_id":null,
        "created_at":"2014-04-11T17:30:28.356Z",
        "updated_at":"2014-04-11T17:30:28.356Z",
        "user_id":2
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Sport",
        "language_user_id":null,
        "created_at":"2014-04-11T17:30:33.059Z",
        "updated_at":"2014-04-11T17:30:36.769Z",
        "user_id":2
    }],
    "language1_id":1,
    "language2_id":5,
}]
```

I don't know how to get a tag id. Now I have this:

```
    public class Word {
        @SerializedName("id")
        public long id;
        @SerializedName("namelanguage1")
        public String nameLanguage1;
        @SerializedName("namelanguage2")
        public String nameLanguage2;

        @SerializedName("language1_id")
        public long language1_id;
        @SerializedName("language2_id")
        public long language2_id;
public ArrayList<Tag> tags;
```

and getters and setters for it. I don't know how to get id of tags. I try understand this example: [example from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321828/parse-list-of-json-objects-using-gson) but still I don't know how to do this.

It's how i have it in code:

```
words = VolleyDemoApplication.obtain().getGson()
                    .fromJson(response, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Word>>() {
                    }.getType());
```

I get values from word like this:

```
 word.getNameLanguage1() + " " +word.getLanguage1_id() + " " + word.getNameLanguage2()+ " " + word.getLanguage2_id() + " " + word.getTags().
```

And here `word.getTags().` and I don't know what write then.

Comment: How are you deserializing the JSON?

Comment: Don't add code to comments. Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Alright. So now you have an `ArrayList<Word>`. Each `Word` has an `id`. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, but I have list of `tags` in `Word`. I need get a id of tag

Comment: Add a `tags` field to your `Word` that is a `Collection` of `Tag` elements: a `Tag[]`, a `List<Tag>`, etc. Gson will deserialize correctly.

Comment: I added `ArrayList`, I have Tag class of course, but i don't know how to get it now.

Comment: What do you mean by _get it_? It's a field of your class. Get an object of `Word`, access its `tags` field (through a getter), retrieve a `Tag` object from the `ArrayList`.

Comment: I need `id` of `tags` which are in `words` and add it to datebase `words_tags` which is many to many

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to point out, i have no clue why this code worked for you, when the json you have printed is not correct.

The actual format is :

```
[
{
    "id": 14,
    "namelanguage1": "aaa",
    "namelanguage2": "das Buch",
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "bbb",
            "language_user_id": null,
            "created_at": "2014-04-11T17:30:28.356Z",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-11T17:30:28.356Z",
            "user_id": 2
        }
    ],
    "language1_id": 5,
    "language2_id": 1 ->> remove the comma here thats in your json text
},
{
    "id": 15,
    "namelanguage1": "zzz",
    "namelanguage2": "yyy",
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "ccc",
            "language_user_id": null,
            "created_at": "2014-04-11T17:30:28.356Z",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-11T17:30:28.356Z",
            "user_id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Sport",
            "language_user_id": null,
            "created_at": "2014-04-11T17:30:33.059Z",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-11T17:30:36.769Z",
            "user_id": 2
        }
    ],
    "language1_id": 1,
    "language2_id": 5 ->> remopve the comma here too
}
]
```

The class word will need a `SerializedName` for `tags` arraylist.

```
@SerializedName(value="tags")
public ArrayList<Tag> tags;
```

You will need to create the tags class too:

```
public class Tag {
@SerializedName(value="id")
private int id;
@SerializedName(value="name")
private String tagName;
@SerializedName(value="language_user_id")
private String languageUserId;
@SerializedName(value="created_at")
private String createdAt;
@SerializedName(value="updated_at")
private String updatedAt;
@SerializedName(value="user_id")
private int userId;

    // create getters and setters or else change the modifiers to public
}
```

You will access id in `Tag` class like this:

```
words.get(0).tags.get(0).getId(); ->> i am using 0 since its the first element, you will need a loop for this
```

or

```
words.get(0).tags.get(0).id;
```

Hope that helps.