# creating a web API for JSON GET Request, how can i create JSON Objects/array for this Pattern

Tags: java, json

suggest me how to work on this, i am having all the data in linkedlinkHashmap like key pair values. i want the output in this format i am trying this but couldn't get exact format

```
{
RequestorId:123
UserId:111
FirstName:john
LastName:peter
Phone_Number:xxx
Email_Address:@com
Address:yyy
Picture:eeee
Work_Location:rrrr
CurrentRole:bca
LanguageSkills:english 
Groups: [
  {
     GroupID: 1
 GroupName:1
 ContentGroup:f&r
 Owner:[
    {
       UserId:111
       FirstName:eee
       LastName:rrr
    }
 ]
  }
  {
     GroupID: 2
 GroupName:2
 ContentGroup:bca
 Owner:[
    {
       UserId:121
       FirstName:www
       LastName:qqq
    },
    {
       UserId:123
       FirstName:ttt
       LastName:uuu
    }
 ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide some code that you have written, so we can check and give some opinion to you.

Comment: You need to tell us the exact problem you're facing, with possibly some relevant code. Are you using a json mapper?

Comment: the json format is invalid, please check [http://json.org/](http://json.org/), the names and string value should be enclosed in double quotes

Answer (score 0):

You could look for a java json library to convert your java data object to json such as gson library eg http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Your example here to converting list of objects to json is similar to the solution offered in this stackoverflow post
[Parse List of JSON objects using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321828/parse-list-of-json-objects-using-gson)
Where mention importantly  match java model to json model via TypeAdapter

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Map <String,Object>` `valueMap` and should have the following classes

```
public Owner{
 int UserId;
 String FirstName;
 String LastName;
}

public Groups{
List<Owner> owner;
int GroupId;
int GroupName;
String ContentGroup;
}
```

and assign values to HashMap

```
valueMap.put("PhoneNumber","xxx");
valueMap.put("Email_Address","@com");
.
.
.
valueMap.put("Groups",<Group>Object);
```

Populate these classes with value and use Google GSON library to convert the hashmap to JSON using

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
String json=gson.toJson(valueMap);
```