# Java Bean Return Value is Null

Tags: java, android, json, javabeans, okhttp

I'm getting a problem with the return value after the post request, the response string contains the requested JSON text but the dataBean is null ??

```
   @Override
    public wDataBean doInBackground(Void... params) {
           wDataBean dataBean = new wDataBean();


        try {

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String responseString = response.body().string();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            dataBean = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), wDataBean.class);

            }
        catch (final IOException e)
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return dataBean;
    }
```

This is a sample of the response:

```
  { "IsOK":true,
    "Response":"Logged in successfully",
    "MyArray":{ "user":"35",
                "email":"email@domain.com",
                "img":"https:\/\/www.mywebsite.com\/uploads\/136_image.png",
                "fname":"First Name",
                "lname":"Last Name",
                "myToken":
                    {   
                        "auth":"xyzxyzyxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz",
                        "expiry":"1980-01-01 00:00:00"
                    }
              },
     "myToken":{}
   }
```

**wDataBean.java**

```
public class wDataBean {

private Main1 main;

public Main1 getMain() {return main;}

public void setMain(Main1 main) {this.main = main;}

class Main1 {

    boolean IsOK;
    String Response;
    JSONArray MyArray;
    int user;
    String email;
    String img;
    String fname;
    String lname;
    JSONArray myToken;
    String auth;
    Date expiry;

    public boolean isOK() {return isOK();}
    public int getUser() {return user;}
    public JSONArray getMyArray() {return MyArray;}
    public String getEmail() {return email;}
    public String getImg() {return img;}
    public String getResponse() {return Response;}
    public Date getExpiry() {return expiry;}
    public JSONArray getMyToken() {return myToken;}
    public String getAuth() {return auth;}
    public String getFname() {return fname;}
    public String getLname() {return lname;}
    public void setAuth(String auth) {this.auth = auth;}
    public void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}
    public void setExpiry(Date expiry) {this.expiry = expiry;}
    public void setFname(String fname) {this.fname = fname;}
    public void setImg(String img) {this.img = img;}
    public void setLname(String lname) {this.lname = lname;}
    public void setMyArray(JSONArray myArray) {MyArray = myArray;}
    public void setMyToken(JSONArray myToken) {this.myToken = myToken;}
    public void setOK(boolean OK) {IsOK = OK;}
    public void setResponse(String response) { Response = response;}
    public void setUser(int user) { this.user = user;}
  }
```

}

The goal is to get **"auth"** and **"expiry"** from **myToken**

Comment: Did stepping through with a debugger reveal anything?

Comment: One possible problem is that [the object might deeper down in the hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210787/gson-fromjson-returns-object-with-null-attrubutes#answer-16211537). And there are other possibilities as well. You should add an example JSON response to your question.

Comment: @nasch: the response string is ok, and it's in json format, but dataBean is null!!

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen : Question is edited with a response JSON sample

Comment: Let's see the data bean definition.

Comment: You could have a look at the other discussion I linked above, but basically the JSON might not match with your `wDataBean` class one-to-one. (Actually you could add that class too...) So, you possibly first need to get a JSON object from the correct level of hierarchy inside the response object and then you can use ´gson.fromJson()´. And even then the field names should match in the JSON object and in your `wDataBean` class.

Comment: There's also an extra comma in `myToken` after `"expiry":"1980-01-01 00:00:00"` that makes the JSON invalid.

Comment: You missed out this @SerializedName("expiry") above your variable.

Answer (score 1):

This should be your bean class -

```
 public class WDataBean {

    @SerializedName("IsOK")
    @Expose
    private Boolean isOK;
    @SerializedName("Response")
    @Expose
    private String response;
    @SerializedName("MyArray")
    @Expose
    private MyArray myArray;
    @SerializedName("myToken")
    @Expose
    private MyToken_ myToken;

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The isOK
    */
    public Boolean getIsOK() {
    return isOK;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param isOK
    * The IsOK
    */
    public void setIsOK(Boolean isOK) {
    this.isOK = isOK;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The response
    */
    public String getResponse() {
    return response;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param response
    * The Response
    */
    public void setResponse(String response) {
    this.response = response;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The myArray
    */
    public MyArray getMyArray() {
    return myArray;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param myArray
    * The MyArray
    */
    public void setMyArray(MyArray myArray) {
    this.myArray = myArray;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @return
    * The myToken
    */
    public MyToken_ getMyToken() {
    return myToken;
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param myToken
    * The myToken
    */
    public void setMyToken(MyToken_ myToken) {
    this.myToken = myToken;
    }

public class MyToken_ {


}
public class MyToken {

@SerializedName("auth")
@Expose
private String auth;
@SerializedName("expiry")
@Expose
private String expiry;

/**
* 
* @return
* The auth
*/
public String getAuth() {
return auth;
}

/**
* 
* @param auth
* The auth
*/
public void setAuth(String auth) {
this.auth = auth;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The expiry
*/
public String getExpiry() {
return expiry;
}

/**
* 
* @param expiry
* The expiry
*/
public void setExpiry(String expiry) {
this.expiry = expiry;
}

}
public class MyArray {

@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private String user;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("img")
@Expose
private String img;
@SerializedName("fname")
@Expose
private String fname;
@SerializedName("lname")
@Expose
private String lname;
@SerializedName("myToken")
@Expose
private MyToken myToken;

/**
* 
* @return
* The user
*/
public String getUser() {
return user;
}

/**
* 
* @param user
* The user
*/
public void setUser(String user) {
this.user = user;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The email
*/
public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

/**
* 
* @param email
* The email
*/
public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The img
*/
public String getImg() {
return img;
}

/**
* 
* @param img
* The img
*/
public void setImg(String img) {
this.img = img;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The fname
*/
public String getFname() {
return fname;
}

/**
* 
* @param fname
* The fname
*/
public void setFname(String fname) {
this.fname = fname;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The lname
*/
public String getLname() {
return lname;
}

/**
* 
* @param lname
* The lname
*/
public void setLname(String lname) {
this.lname = lname;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The myToken
*/
public MyToken getMyToken() {
return myToken;
}

/**
* 
* @param myToken
* The myToken
*/
public void setMyToken(MyToken myToken) {
this.myToken = myToken;
}

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me the class wDataBean?

But I venture to say that this can solve

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
```